# Android simulate stream of touch events in view

Tags: android, automation, touch, motionevent

I'm trying to develop an Android app that would help me automate some repetitive actions in a view (such as scrolling to a fixed location and clicking a button in a fixed location).

Using `MotionEvent.obtain()` I was able to simulate `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` (for views where I only need to click at a location already on screen), but when I try to scroll down (using `ACTION_MOVE`) it doesn't work.

Has anyone been able to perform an automated scroll to a location in a view of their app? Any help or info in this regard would be great.